# error: lvalue required as increment operand without an error line

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-definition

I've seen a similar post on StackOverflow about this error code, but theirs seemed to have an error code line, and they were also attempting something slightly different in their function.

I'm trying to count the number of a specified character in a string (inputting `p` and `apple` would return 2, for example). At some point, my method broke down. I've been scouring my code for what specific increment operator is causing this, but without an error code line I don't know which one is causing it, and I've messed around with both.

I'm not sure which of these variables isn't modifiable, but all it tells me is:

> main.cpp:11:30: error: lvalue required as increment operand

If anyone could take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong, I would really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
      
int main() {
   string b;
   char a;
   int i;
   int counter(string b) {
   counter = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) 
      if (b[a] == a), counter++);
      counter = i;
      return counter;
}
   cin >> a;
   cin >> b;
   return counter(b);
   }
   

   return 0;
}
```

PS, I know this code has multiple other errors. It's a work in progress, but I am trying to focus on this operand issue first.

I've been trying to redefine variables for both `counter` and `i`, as I'm not sure which one is causing the issue, but nothing has fixed it. For example, within the `for` loop, I tried setting `counter` equal to some variable, but that didn't help. I think it's possible I messed up the syntax too within the `for` loop, and I spent some time in there, but if that's the issue I didn't fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to define a function named `counter` inside `main`? You can't nest functions in C++. Put it outside main.

Comment: And you also have random parenthesis out of place. You appear to be making a common mistake of attempting to write the entire program at once, and only then trying to compile and run it. This is the wrong approach. The correct approach is to write just a few lines of code, at first, compile, run, and test to make sure they work correctly, before writing a few more lines of code, and so on until the whole program is done. I did not write all ten thousand lines of code, in one of my libraries, all at once. It'll be simpler for you to start over, with an empty file, and proceed slowly.

Comment: @teapot418 I was trying to do that. Thank you! I'm editing the code now

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are correct, that is exactly what I did. Very unfortunate results. Thank you for the recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is invalid

In this line

```
int counter(string b); {
                    ^^^
```

you declared a function with the name `counter` (see the semicolon).

After the function declaration there is followed a compound statement

```
int counter(string b); {
counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) 
   if (b[a] == a), `counter++`);
   return counter;
}
```

within which the function name `counter` is used as a variable as for example `counter++`

So the compiler issues the error message

> "main.cpp:11:30: error: lvalue required as increment operand".

because you are using the function name and trying to apply to it the post-increment operator ++. But the function designator in this case in implicitly converted to a pointer to the function and it is not an lavlue.

After the compound statement you are calling the function counter though it is not defined

```
return counter(b);
```

It seems you are trying to define the function `counter` within the function `main`. You may not do that.

Also the function should accept two arguments: the string and the character.

Your program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t counter( const std::string &s, char c )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( char ch : s )
    {
        if ( c == ch ) ++count;
    }  

    return count;
}   


int main() 
{
   std::string s;
   char c;

   std::cin >> s;
   std::cin >> c;

   std::cout << counter( s, c ) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hi Vlad from Moscow. I'm sorry that there are plenty of idiotic mistakes in here, this is my first C++ lab, but I couldn't figure out my operand issue and was hoping for clarification. I appreciate all of the comments on other areas I could improve though. I really appreciate that code you sent me and I'll make sure to keep all of that in mind.

Comment: Thank you, that's a much better way to do it than my way. Can I ask why you wrote &s in the counter parameter?

Comment: FYI, the entire `counter()` function can be replaced with the standard [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) or [`std::ranges::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/count) algorithm, eg: `std::cout << std::count( s.begin(), s.end(), c ) << '\n';` or `std::cout << std::ranges::count( s, c ) << '\n';`

Comment: @robotkisser If you pass a string by reference then neither its copy will be created. Otherwise passing by value (as in your initial function) is inefficient because the function will deal with a created copy of the string passed to the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's helpful to know, I'll be needing to do a lot of tallying for future labs so that'll save me a lot of time.